# Unable to list compute instances in one project

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am trying to get a list of all GCP compute instances in all projects that I have access to. However, there is one project that keeps giving me a "permission denied" answer, and I cannot figure out why...

In order to authenticate, I have created a service account in one of the projects (let's call it `sa1`, in `project_a`). Then, at the organization level, I have given that SA the Compute Admin role. And everything works fine, for all of the projects, except one (let's call this non-working one `project_x`).

Now I am using the `computeService.Instances.AggregatedList` call, which according to [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/aggregatedList) needs the `compute.instances.list` permission. If I go to IAM&Admin/Policy Troubleshooter and check, I find out that it should work:

```
Access granted for API call for sa1@project_a, compute.instances.list, projects/project_x.

If this outcome was unexpected, contact your support team for further assistance.
```

However, if I try to actually run the code, as soon as I hit that project I get:

```
googleapi: Error 403: Permission denied on resource project project_x, forbidden
```

The code is written in Go, based on the sample in [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/aggregatedList). The actual call I am using looks like this:

```
func getInstances ( ctx context.Context, cs *compute.Service, projectName string) {
        req := cs.Instances.AggregatedList(projectName)
        err := req.Pages(ctx, func(page *compute.InstanceAggregatedList) error {
                for name, instancesScopedList := range page.Items {
                        if len(instancesScopedList.Instances) > 0 {
                                fmt.Printf("===== %v =====\n", name)
                                for _, instance := range instancesScopedList.Instances {
                                        fmt.Printf("-- %#v, %#v\n", instance.Name, instance.NetworkInterfaces[0].AccessConfigs[0].NatIP)
                                }
                        }
                }
                return nil
        })
        if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("Error getting list!")
                log.Fatal(err)
        }
}
```

I honestly have no idea what could be causing this, and no idea how to troubleshoot further. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Oh, and if it matters - there are actually no compute engine instances in project_x. But this should not be a problem - I have other projects with no instances, and I simply get an empty list from them.

Comment: The "no compute engine" is the right way. Great idea to check this. Just go a step further: can you check if the [compute API](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/compute.googleapis.com) is activated on the project_x?

Comment: I didn't think of that - but I just checked, and the Compute Engine API is enabled on that project.

Comment: Arg.... It way my first idea. With a closer look to your code, you use the `projectName string` as parameter. Are you sure that the project name equal the project_id for this project?

Comment: That was it! Thank you! I had one uppercase character in the project name, which became lowercase in the project ID - that tiny difference was enough. I guess that's what I get for not reading the documentation carefully (I totally missed the fact that the argument should be an ID :) ). Well... at least I named my variables correctly :P

If you would post this as an answer, I will gladly accept it. Thank you once again!!